# В чем разница между методом val jquery и свойством value в javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Когда перебираю массив из инпутов, то метод val() jquery выдает ошибку, а вот свойство value javascript выводит значение атрибута value. В чем тут подвох?

Comment: Какую ошибку? Как обращаетесь к val()? Пример кода в студию и саму ошибку

Comment: _В чем разница между..._ `val()` - метод коллекции jQuery, `value` - свойство DOM элемента.

Comment: подозреваю, что идет попытка вызвать `val()` Не на jQuery объекте, а на html элементе, у которого этого метода нет.

Comment: Но без кода ничего нельзя сказать. Добавляй пример своего кода

Answer (score 3):

Разница между методом val и свойством value довольно большая:

Свойство находится непосредственно в элементе, и получает значение как есть.

Если посмотреть реализацию [метода val](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/56136897f241db22560b58c3518578ca1453d5c7/src/attributes/val.js#L15) и опустить проверку на то, передали в метод параметр или нет и сразу перейти к [получению значения](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/56136897f241db22560b58c3518578ca1453d5c7/src/attributes/val.js#L20) можно отметить, что сначала проверяется [наличие хуков](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/56136897f241db22560b58c3518578ca1453d5c7/src/attributes/val.js#L24):

```
if ( hooks &&
    "get" in hooks &&
    ( ret = hooks.get( elem, "value" ) ) !== undefined
) {
    return ret;
}
```

И если они есть, то выполняется соответствующая функция.

Если хуков нет, то получается значение, с помощью свойства `value`, и если полученное значение является строкой - перед возвратом из функции из строки будут удалены символы `\r` с помощью замены по регулярному выражению [`rreturn`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/56136897f241db22560b58c3518578ca1453d5c7/src/attributes/val.js#L12)

---

Ошибку при вызове метода val можно получить, если пытаться вызвать этот метод у нативного html элемента, а не у объекта jQuery. Для решения, достаточно обернуть имеющийся элемент, в объект:

```
$(element).val();
```

Answer (score 1):

`.val()` - метод, применяемый к объекту JQ. Использование объекта jQuery начинается с вызова одноименной функции - `$("селектор").`
`.value` - применяется к элементу DOM. Работа с элементом DOM начинается с  `document.getElementByТипСелектора("егоНазвание").`

Для наглядности примера - [ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/5p45m9qf/2/), нужно **открыть консоль** в браузере! И кликнуть единственную кнопку.

Comment: что значит _те, что начинаются с $()_? *те, что начинаются с document.getElementBy___*? Что если `document.getElementBy_` не используется пользователем напрямую?

Comment: слегка исправил. хотелось бы донести информацию максимально доступно и просто.

Comment: Но в коде может использовать только jQuery, и все равно  попадаться элементы, например [немного измененный твой пример](https://jsfiddle.net/5p45m9qf/3/).

Comment: И все еще непонятно что значит элемент DOM, который обычно начинается с ..., или  объект JQ, который обычно начинается с...? Как элемент или объект могут начинаться?

Comment: this.val is not a function
если я правильно понял, что там изменилось.

Comment: Да, мы вроде как в объекте jQuery, то есть _вроде как_ нигде не получаем элемент напрямую, но все равно работает с элементом, а не jQuery объектом

Comment: Кажется понял, что было не так с  _"начинается с"_ , исправил.
По поводу вызова элемента DOM из объекта jQ - тут на пальцах объяснить сложно будет человеку. Можно предложить внушительные статьи про конструктор/прототип в jquery.

Comment: Да, сейчас лучше. По поводу поведения `this` в функциях - у нас есть отдельный вопрос с ответами.